# Waiting for certain amout of reactions with discord

Tags: python, discord.py

So i need to make a command which will check for 10 next reactions after command execution and collect them in list, but i dont get how can i properly collect certain amout of reactions.
At first i tried to execute wait_for("reaction_add") in for loop with certain range, but it doesnt work at all. Any ideas how to design it properly?

```
@client.command()
   async def get_reactions(ctx, amount):
      messages_list = list()
      for _ in range(int(amount)):
         reaction, _ = await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
         messages_list.append(reaction)
      print(messages_list)
```

Comment: _but it doesnt work at all._ What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is work nice. But it's check reaction for messages which send after start your bot. You don't get reaction for messages which send before start your bot. From docs:

> if the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called.

[Link for docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add)

Try to start your bot, send message, call your command and add reaction for your message before your command.

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Oh, you're right, missed that part about cache, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark it as a solution?